# How to create common file (available for all users on local machine) in Adobe Air

Tags: file, air, adobe, cross-platform

I need to store some data (strings, dates etc) and these data would be available for all users in local machine. Not depended on Admin or Guest started the application - it would be able to read/write these strings and dates.
SharedObjects are belong only user, which started the program.

- File.applicationStorageDirectory
- File.desktopDirectory
- File.documentsDirectory
- File.userDirectory

They all are user related.

*File.applicationDirectory* — is read-only.

Please, do not propose to use some thing like *C:\settings.txt* etc, because i need cross-platform solution and without casual user deletions/rewritings etc.

I need some thing like *C:\Users\AllUsers* or *C:\Users\Public* folder, but cross-platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, it isn't possible to do this by current Adobe Air API. EncryptedLocalStore also wouldn't be helpful for you.